# Preposition when doing some job with software?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition should I use if I do something and I use some software to help me in my job. I mean, which one is correct?

1. I computed it ***by*** Excel.
2. I computed it ***using*** Excel.
3. I computed it ***with*** Excel.
4. I computed it ***with the help of*** Excel.

Comment: Please add more detail to this question explaining which you think might be correct, and why, and any research you've done?  Otherwise this question might be closed.

Comment: "computed it *by* Excel" sounds very weird to this US English speaker.  "using" or "with" sounds much more natural.

Answer (score 1):

> I computed it using Excel.

good

> I computed it with Excel.

good

> I computed it with help of Excel.

should be "I computed it with the help of Excel."

> I computed it by Excel.

Not exactly. It could be "I computed it, by using Excel!"